# How do I find a persons profile?

Tags: fallen-london

Ok this is probably a really dumb question but I just started playing Fallen London yesterday and someone sent me a calling card right away. I don't know who they are, if they are someone I want to be friends with, or how to find out anything about them. I guess I just want to know how I can view this persons profile (or whatever Fallen London calls it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't been able to find an actual search for other users, but you can view anyone's Journal by visiting

```
http://fallenlondon.storynexus.com/Profile/<user_name_here>
```

where you replace `<user_name_here>` with the name you're looking for.